# Wrong query generated with @OrderBy annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations

I am using Hibernate3 and i have an entity with the following collection:

```
@ManyToMany  
@JoinTable(name = "buys_publishers", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="buy_id", referencedColumnName = "buy_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id", referencedColumnName = "publisher_id"))  
@OrderBy("name")  
private List<Publisher> publishers;
```

(fetch and cascade decelerations omitted)

The target entity (Publisher) inherits from an entity that holds the "name" attribute on which the @orderby is activated.

here is the target entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="publishers")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="account_id")
public class Publisher extends Account{

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name = "publisher_id")
   private Long publisherId;

   public Long getPublisherId() {
      return publisherId;
   }

   public void setPublisherId(Long publisherId) {
      this.publisherId = publisherId;
   }


}
```

and the super class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accounts")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Account implements Serializable{

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


   @Id
   @Column(name="id",unique=true, nullable=false )
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "account_type")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   private AccountType accountType;

   public long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public AccountType getAccountType() {
      return accountType;
   }

   public void setAccountType(AccountType accountType) {
      this.accountType = accountType;
   }

}
```

the query that Hibernate generates is:

```
select publishers0_.buy_id as buy1_1_, publishers0_.publisher_id as publisher2_1_, publisher1_.account_id as id6_0_, publisher1_1_.account_type as account2_6_0_, publisher1_1_.name as name6_0_, publisher1_.publisher_id as publisher1_18_0_ from buys_publishers publishers0_ left outer join publishers publisher1_ on publishers0_.publisher_id=publisher1_.publisher_id left outer join accounts publisher1_1_ on publisher1_.account_id=publisher1_1_.id where publishers0_.buy_id=? order by accounts.name asc
```

it is clear from the query that the order by should be on publisher1_1_, am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [HHH-4260 - @OrderBy does not work with inherited properties](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4260) (and I wouldn't expect a short term resolution).